Could I own many cookie cutter homes in a LLC, sell 1 home to another LLC I own for X, and then use that X as a comp value for my homes with the bank?
so let’s say I owned a piece of land. Took that piece of land, which could hold 20 houses, and built two for 100k a pop. Could I then sell those for X, to another company of mine, then build two more for 100k a pop and use the X value for comps/appraisal?
I.E. Build for 100, sell for 275, and pull comps against my own sales of 275. Then receiving 206,250 in equity. Effectively making 100k. Even if taxed on the two sales the profit would remain enough.

The quick answer is 'no, that wouldnt work'. The longer answer is: "no, fraud is illegal for both tax and financing purposes".

I’m voting to close this question because we don't allow questions intending to commit fraud.

I was actually unsure if it was, and so that seems be an answer in itself.
Is it legally fraud, or just sounds like it? I agree

Well it just wouldn't work - when securing financing, the bank would want an independant appraisal of the homes you are asking to put security on. Value of recent sales might form part of that, but that should only happen if the sales are at 'arms-length'; hiding the fact that you sold them to yourself would, if you even could, would in itself likely constitute fraud. I'm not a lawyer, but intending to deceive your bank / the IRS with a shell game like this should fall quite neatly into the 'fraud' box.

Also - note that the funds received as a loan from a bank are not 'profit', as you do in fact need to pay them back [it appears you may not have intended to do that, either...]

No. It would be a typical equity strip with a renter paying the note off. Getting traditional appraisal using skewed comps. But I saw the problem in the idea, and have no plans to carry this forward. Just had never heard of the concept of arms-length transaction

Also they would be sold, fully sold, to another company. Entirely separate company, but I hear the problem in trying to skew appraisal value. Assuming it could even be skewed by selling similar properties in a nearby area, using sq/ft and bedrooms to sort of “set” the comp

Generally, if you see what looks like an obvious scheme, others have tried it before, the IRS is aware of it, and the laws, codes, and regulations are written to prevent it.

Purposefully giving the bank 'skewed comps' = fraud. And, "Entirely separate company" when you own that other company, is still not an arms-length transaction. Yes, this is still fraud.

So if I understand the scam correctly, you'll "sell" a property to yourself through a different controlled entity and then present it to the bank as an arm's-length transaction for loan purposes.
In the US that would be considered bank fraud, see 18 USC 1344:

Whoever knowingly executes, or attempts to execute, a scheme or artifice—
(1) to defraud a financial institution; or
(2) to obtain any of the moneys, funds, credits, assets, securities, or other property owned by, or under the custody or control of, a financial institution, by means of false or fraudulent pretenses, representations, or promises;
shall be fined not more than $1,000,000 or imprisoned not more than 30 years, or both.


Appreciate the advice, I had not heard of that, but I did see the shadiness involved! Just didn’t know to what extent, or if it was ‘legally’ bad

Because sometimes a property must be sold/transferred between related parties, in the US the local government will designate the transaction as one not to be used to determine property values.
These types of transactions may legitimately be done while putting the property in a trust, or after a divorce, or between siblings during the period the estate is being settled.
Disguising the relationship to fool the bank or the local government would be a crime.

Thank you, I appreciate the detailed helpful response! The trust information specifically!
